# Custom frame by frame animation in iOS

Tags: ios

Is there a way to perform an animation in iOS where **at every frame** I can do some calculations, update constraints and perform a layout (`layoutIfNeeded()`)?

The animation I'm trying to achieve seems impossible to do using the standard way of doing a constraint animation, which internally works by calculating just two frames, the first and the last one, so `layoutIfNeeded()` is called just twice. In the intermediate frames, view positions are determined by simply interpolating between the first and last frames. I want to recalculate the layout at every frame.

Comment: Can you give a small example?

Answer (score 1):

You can always try to use `CALayer` animations, depending on your needs.

This is not a direct answer but answer pointing to a place where you can find answer: https://www.objc.io/issues/12-animations/